# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 4130

Tags: json, gson

I have the following json: (I see a map in an object called locations)
I make a gson call to convert it to an object with a map.
Maybe I am seeing the json wrong.
What I am doing wrong?

```
{
  "locations": {
    "0": {
      "locationNo": "10014",
      "inventoryLocationNo": "10014"
    },
    "1": {
      "locationNo": "10022",
      "inventoryLocationNo": "10022"
    },
    "2": {
      "locationNo": "10030",
      "inventoryLocationNo": "10030"
    },
 },
  "errors": {}
}
```

## Here is my code

I get the the exception when I make this call:

```
BATOLocationIDAPIResponse responseObject = gson.fromJson(container.body, BATOLocationIDAPIResponse.class);
```

## Here is my code

```
/**
 * POJO that represents the response wrapper for a Location API call.
 *
 */
public class BATOLocationIDAPIResponse {
    private BATOLocationContainer locations;
    private List<String> errors;
    }
    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
    public class BATOLocationContainer {
        private Map<String, BATOAPILocation> locations;
     }
}
// Location object
    public class BATOAPILocation {
        public String locationNo;
        public String inventoryLocationNo;
     }
```

Comment: you defined errors as List of Strings in your response object, but in the response, errors is a map

Answer (score 0):

You have `private List<String> errors;`, but your JSON shows `"errors": {}` this should be an Array like `"errors": []`

Comment: Thanks for reply. That helped me a lot. Somehow I was paying more attention to the section with actual data.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped you I would be glad if you would mark this answer as accepted ;-)